# How to execute java class and the run all the suite.xml files using POM.xml

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, appium, maven-surefire-plugin

We have a java main class which will read the input data from excel and generate multiple suite.xml files inside a folder ExecutionSuites. (Total number of .xml depends on the input provided in excel)

I want to execute the java main class 1st and then execute these suiteXmlFiles using pom.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tried below code but it does not run the java main class 1st during execution:                         <properties>
<exec.mainClass>src.test.java.Package1.mainClass1</exec.mainClass>
</properties>

Comment: For running the all suites, below configuration in maven-surefire-plugin plugin ends with error          <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
     <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>ExecutionSuites/*.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding something.  `main()` methods don't get executed by surefire when you run `mvn clean test.`

When running Tests, you do not expect a `Class (with main)` to run first.   That is part of your `*Test` classes.

Your main class logic could be part of your `@Test` method instead:

```
public class Test1{

  @Test
  public voidTestMethod1(){
    MainClass example = new MainClass(); 
    example.loadData();
    //assert something.

  }
}
```

---

Other helpful tips:  Lets say you want to run `specific logic`, before your suit runs, you can use `@BeforeSuite` annotation

```
public class MyFirstTest 
{
    @Test
    public void testCase() {
    }
 
    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {
        System.out.println("Before Suite method");
    }
 
    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite() {
        System.out.println("After Suite method");
    }
 
    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        System.out.println("Before Test method");
    }
     
    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        System.out.println("After Test method");
    }
     
    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("Before Class method");
    }
 
    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass() {
        System.out.println("After Class method");
    }
 
    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        System.out.println("Before Method");
    }
 
    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        System.out.println("After Method");
    }
}
```

---

Then your sunfire-plugin will run your Test files:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
        <file>src/test/resources/testng1.xml</file>
        <file>src/test/resources/testng2.xml</file>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
      <properties>
        <property>
          <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
          <value>2</value>
        </property>
      </properties>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```